# Spectral Measure of Unitary Operators

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

It is known that for a unitary operator $U$: $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space, there exist a probability measure $\mu$ on the boundary of the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$, $\partial\mathbb{D}$, and a linear mapping $V: \mathcal{H}\rightarrow L^2(\partial\mathbb{D}, d\mu)$ (which universally exists and does not depend on $U$?), such that

a. $\forall x\in\mathcal{H}$, $V(Ux)=zV(x)$;

b. $\forall x, y\in\mathcal{H}$, $(x, y)_{\mathcal{H}}=(Vx, Vy)_{L^2(\partial\mathbb{D}, d\mu)}$

For this statement, I am wondering if it is true that two unitary operators $U_1, U_2$ have the same spectral measure $\mu$ if and only if there exists a unitary operator $W$ such that $U_1=W^*U_2W$.

Comment: (a) is stated wrong; when you say there exists $z$ such that etc you're saying that $V(Ux)$ is a scalar multiple of $V(x)$. What's  true is that $V(Ux)(z)=zV(x)(z)$ for _every_ $z\in\partial\Bbb D$.

Comment: Also I'm puzzled by "which...does not depend on $V$". The way you wrote that sounds like you're asking whether $V$ depends on $V$, which makes no sense. It would make sense to ask whether $V$ depends on $U$;  the answer is yes it does..

Comment: @YimingXu You need to put "@username" (with no spaces and a space after) for the person to get a notification. (The owner of the Question or Answer is notified automatically.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes @DavidC.Ullrich  I have corrected them above. By the way, I am wondering if you also have an answer for the other question I have at the end? I would appreciate if you could let me know. ^_^

Comment: The result you state as known is false. Eigenspaces of multiplication by $z$ on $L^2(\partial\mathbb{D},\mu)$ are one-dimensional. That's not true of a general unitary operator $U : \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$.